# Corruption of JSON object from Google Contacts OAuth response

Tags: json, curl, google-oauth, google-contacts-api, chunked-encoding

I'm using OAuth 2.0 with Google Contacts. It's all working well (using CURL with Visual Studio C++ 
to make requests) but sometimes (recently?) my returned JSON object instead of looking like this:

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.AHES6ZTtm7SuokEB-RGtbBty9IIlNiP9-eNMMQKtXdMP3sfjL1Fc",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"refresh_token" : "1/HKSmLFXzqP0leUihZp2xUt3-5wkU7Gmu2Os_eBnzw74"
}
```

looks like this:

```
{
00000001


00000001

00000001

00000001
"
00000001
a
00000001
c
00000001
c
00000001
e
00000001
s
00000001
s
00000001
_
00000001
t
00000001
o
00000001
k
00000001
e
00000001
n
00000001
"
00000001

00000001
:
000001

7c
"ya29.1.AADtN_VutXzy-bvGQsNaVusm6NZce9kPzbg1gcjwwZza6Utll4UsXGgBSSjkYfM",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600
}
```

which makes it difficult to extract the data. Any ideas? 
This is how I'm doing the CURL request:

```
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

struct curl_slist *headers=NULL; 
curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset: UTF-8");
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL,(LPCSTR)requesturl);
if(postfields) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postfields);
}
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CGoogleContacts::function_pt);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &gs_strLastResponse);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
CURLcode result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl); 
return result == CURLE_OK;
```

Thanks
Greg Chapman

Comment: OK I've worked out it's to do with the chunked encoding. So quite valid - but is there a way of asking for the response not to be chunked (sometimes it isn't)?